# Can we create Virtual machine using Command?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I need to create the Virtual machine using command and have to set IP address and password also. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is perfectly possible with vagrant and minimal setup(note: some config files are needed).

I assume you're using vmware for this?
you can find everything you'll need here:
https://www.vagrantup.com/vmware

If using virtualbox is fine too, just go to: 
https://www.vagrantup.com/

And when using vagrant, the next step would be using it in combination with [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/get-started?&__hssc=&__hstc=5198188.ed6c35d22fed2734144ac90818f166c3.1415110980317.1415110980317.1415113916645.2&hsCtaTracking=5f754c20-f6b9-446a-9a66-5c0131cf21ce%7C5feefe51-9ea0-496e-9f07-3cc63c158da3),which is a Desired State configuration tool, provisioner, config management,.. or from the ansible site:

Ansible is a radically simple IT automation engine that automates cloud provisioning, configuration management, application deployment, intra-service orchestration, and many other IT needs.